# Python: Execute a line by user input?

Tags: python, text, input, io

I am currently working on a game and I was wondering if there was any way to execute commands like a text file by user input?

I would like to make it where the text doesn't pop up all at once, but where you could do something like "Press any key to continue" and when they do that, the next wall of text appears. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Python doesn't support "Press any key to continue". It only supports "Press enter to continue"

Comment: Before you decide to make a game, I *highly* recommend reading the first 9 chapters of the Python tutorial. In any case, what you want is raw_input() for Python 2 and input() for Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **easy** way is:

```
input('Press Enter to continue')
```

(in Python 3; `raw_input` instead in Python 2) but that will indeed wait for an Enter, AKA return, before continuing.

If you're really adamant about the **any**-key part you'll have to get "down and dirty".  In Microsoft Windows only,

```
import msvcrt
def wait():
    msvcrt.getch()
print('Press any key to continue')
wait()
```

will work -- but it will fail on Linux or MacOSX; you'll need other approaches for those.  So please let us know which platform(s) you need to support and we'll figure something out!-)

Comment: Well they way I had figured it out is by this: 
`print ("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE")
 user = input(" ")
 if user == " ":
    print (hike1.read())`

Comment: That becomes a secret code that only prints the next wall of text if the user knows to hit the space bar then the Enter key. You want it to scroll on anything the user enters, so just get the input and throw it away without checking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `input("Press Enter to continue")` between printing each wall of text.

Comment: `raw_input` for python 2.x